# jQuery POST php mysql (mobile)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mobile, post

Estou tentando fazer um post com *jQuery mobile* em meu servidor interno, quando executo o post pelo navegador ele insere o registro funcionando 100% com código exatamente igual, agora quando faço o teste no simulador (*Intel XDK*) e também com o *APP Preview* no meu celular o POST não funciona, simplesmente não acontece nada.

**registrar.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Blank Standard HTML5 Web App Template

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<style>

    @-ms-viewport { width: 100vw ; min-zoom: 100% ; zoom: 100% ; }  @viewport { width: 100vw ; min-zoom: 100% zoom: 100% ; }
    @-ms-viewport { user-zoom: fixed ; min-zoom: 100% ; }           @viewport { user-zoom: fixed ; min-zoom: 100% ; }
</style>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function post() {

        var nome        = $('#nome').val();
        var email       = $('#email').val();
        var banco       = $('#banco').val();
        var agencia     = $('#agencia').val();
        var conta       = $('#conta').val();
        var telefone    = $('#telefone').val();
        var senha       = $('#senha').val();

        $.post('http://192.168.0.10/enviar.php',{nome:nome,email:email,banco:banco,agencia:agencia,conta:conta,telefone:telefone,senha:senha},
            function(data){
                alert(data);
        });
    }
```

```
<div data-role="footer">
    <br />
    <br />
   <h1>Crie sua conta</h1>
</div>

    <form method="post" action="#">
        <label>Nome:</label>        
        <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" placeholder="">

        <label>Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="">

        <label>Banco:</label>
        <input type="text" name="banco" id="banco" placeholder="">

        <label>Agência:</label>
        <input type="number" name="agencia" id="agencia" placeholder="">

        <label>Conta:</label>
        <input type="number" name="conta" id="conta" placeholder="">          

        <label>Telefone:</label>
        <input type="tel" name="telefone" id="telefone" placeholder="">

        <label>Senha:</label>
        <input type="password" name="senha" id="senha" placeholder="">

        <a class="ui-btn ui-mini ui-btn-b" onclick="post();">Registrar</a>
    </form>

<a href="index.html" class="ui-btn ui-mini" data-rel="back">Voltar</a>
```

Codigo (beckend) do meu php que insere:

**enviar.php**

```
<?php 
$nome       = $_POST['nome'];
$email      = $_POST['email'];
$telefone   = $_POST['telefone'];
$banco      = $_POST['banco'];
$agencia    = $_POST['agencia'];
$conta      = $_POST['conta'];
$senha      = $_POST['senha'];

$conexao = mysql_pconnect("localhost","root","") or die (mysql_error());
$banco = mysql_select_db("aplicativo");

$nome       = mysql_real_escape_string($nome);
$email      = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
$telefone   = mysql_real_escape_string($telefone);
$banco      = mysql_real_escape_string($banco);
$agencia    = mysql_real_escape_string($agencia);
$conta      = mysql_real_escape_string($conta);
$senha      = mysql_real_escape_string($senha);

$insert = mysql_query("insert into usuarios (nome,email,telefone,banco,agencia,conta,senha) values ('{$nome}','{$email}','{$telefone}','{$banco}','{$agencia}','{$conta}', '{$senha}')");
mysql_close($conexao);
if($insert) {
    print "Cadastro Realizado!";
}else {
    print "Erro ao Cadastrar!";
}
```

Estou realizado o post corretamente ? Existe algum outro método especifico para realizar este POST ?

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, onde está o servidor de testes que vc está usando "192.168.0.10"?
Se está na sua maquina vc só vai conseguir usar pelo navegador da sua máquina mesmo, provavelmente o celular não está conseguindo encontrar "192.168.0.10" pq tá na sua maquina isso.